# Google Api Availability issue

Tags: android, api, maps

I'm trying to use Google Maps API in my android project.
When I call the following function

```
public boolean checkGoogleServices(){
        Log.d(TAG, "isServicesOk: checking google services version");
        int available = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Home.this);

        if (available == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){


            Log.d(TAG, "isServicesOk: Google Play Services is working");
            Toast.makeText(this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;

        }
        else if(GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isUserResolvableError(available)){

            Log.d(TAG, "isServicesOk: an error occured but we can fix it");
            Dialog dialog = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(Home.this, available, ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST);
            dialog.show();


        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "You can't make maps request", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
        return false;

    }
```

the result of `if (available == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)`is `true` in fact the program writes on console the log "google play services is working" but right after that it goes out the if and return `false`.

Google Play Services are correctly installed in my SDK.

Comment: it returns `false` because you have written `return false` and at no time do you return anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method returns `false` because you have written `return false` and at no time do you return anything else.

If you wish to return `true` when the service is available add a `return` statement inside the conditional.

```
public boolean checkGoogleServices(){
        boolean isAvailable = false;
        Log.d(TAG, "isServicesOk: checking google services version");
        int available = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Home.this);

        if (available == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
            isAvailable = true;
            Log.d(TAG, "isServicesOk: Google Play Services is working");
            Toast.makeText(Home.this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isUserResolvableError(available)){

            Log.d(TAG, "isServicesOk: an error occured but we can fix it");
            Dialog dialog = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(Home.this, available, ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST);
            dialog.show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(Home.this, "You can't make maps request", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return isAvailable;
    }
```

The `return` statement will exit the method so that no further code is executed.

You will need to decide what you want to return in the

```
}else if(GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isUserResolvableError(available)){
```

portion of the code. If you want to return `false` then the above code will work fine.

Comment: sorry my bad I've forgot to copy the return inside the if. I'm going to update the question

Comment: @gabboSonc :: no other information being written to the log other than `"isServicesOk: Google Play Services is working`? Is the `Toast` being shown?

Comment: the toast is shown. right before the return true the program jumps outside the if and return false.

Comment: @gabboSonc :: look at the slight modification I made to the code. It really should not be necessary, but I added a local boolean variable `isAvailable`. see if that works. We can look at the rest in a next step.

Comment: sounds good. now it returns true. in main function i've tested with if (checkGoogleServices()==true) and it works correctly.

Comment: @gabboSonc :: Try to put a `Log.d` behind the `Toast`. And just to be on the save side use `Home.this` instead of just `this`. I have no idea why the method would jump over `return true`. But debugging is really all you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the boolean and print

```
    public static boolean checkPlayServices(Activity activity) {
        final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
        GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
                apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(activity, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST)
                        .show();
 Log.d(TAG, "This device have google play services");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "This device does not have google play services");
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Now print checkPlayServices(activity)